# Making sure div doesnt get bigger than the text - wrapping and overflowing

Tags: css

I have a div that is being rendered from a data coming from the server.
the data sometimes contains a sequance of chracters without any spacing that can be for example "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" and "--------------------"
when these sequences are very long my div is rendered in a way that the div overcome the scroll and boundaries and looks bad.

I have tried all solution with word breadk and word wraps and so on. but the issue is that if I fix the -----------------  (with SOH sigh for example) and it is being wrapped up perfectly then the other case is not good as the letter case ("xxxxxxxxxxx....") is cutting it as well as so regular words like current will be also splitted into 2 rows.

I need a solutoion for both IE and chrome

Comment: Could you post your html and css to us ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. For breaking words that are longer than one line, a simple `word-wrap:break-word` is enough. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynpwas49/). Works in all browsers, and words that are short enough to fit on a line will not be broken in any case. So what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes. Here is the fiddler to simulate my problem. Please see that the aaaaa is also being cutt off.                                                   https://jsfiddle.net/7vcw66cd/